# Gson StackOverflow Error Android

Tags: android, gson

I get a `StackOverflow` error anytime I try to `Serialize` a `JSON String` to my `POJO Object` that have two `Constructors`

```
public class ObjectClass extends BaseObservable implements Serializable {

    @Inject Realm realm;
    private String TAG = "ObjectClass";

    private String name;
    private String address;

    public ObjectClass() {
    }

    public ObjectClass(Context context) {
        ((MainApplication) context.getApplicationContext()).getMainAppComponent().inject(this);
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setname(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    @Bindable
    public String getAddress() {
        return address;
    }

    public void setaddress(String address) {
        this.address = address;
        Realmaddress result = realm.where(Realmaddress.class).equalTo("id", address).findFirst();
        if (result != null)
            Log.e(TAG, result.toString());
    }
}
```

Should I remove this constructor

```
public ObjectClass(Context context) {
    ((MainApplication) context.getApplicationContext()).getMainAppComponent().inject(this);
}
```

everything works fine. But, If I leave it, I experience a StackOverFlow Error.

```
String testJson = "{\n" +
                "\t\"name\" : \"Test Name\",\n" +
                "\t\"address\" : \"Test Address\"\n" +
                "}"

Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().setDateFormat("yyyy'-'MM'-'dd'T'HH':'mm':'ss'.'SSS'Z'").setPrettyPrinting().create();
    ObjectClass objectClass = gson.fromJson(testJson, ObjectClass.class);
```

Everything just hangs and after a while, I get A `StackOverflow` error

**EDIT 1**

So, after deep debugging. I noticed the constructor wasn't the problem. This was `@Inject Realm realm;` So, I tried to do this `@Expose(deserialize = false, serialize = false)
    @Inject Realm realm;` which isn't fixing it too.

**EDIT 2**

I edited my `GSON Exclusion Strategy` to look like this. But, it doesn't fix it even after it enters the if block and logs that it exists

```
public class CustomGsonParser {

    public static Gson returnCustomParser(){
        return new GsonBuilder()
                .setExclusionStrategies(new ExclusionStrategy() {
                    @Override
                    public boolean shouldSkipField(FieldAttributes f) {
                        if (f.getAnnotation(Inject.class) != null ||
                                f.getDeclaringClass().equals(RealmObject.class) ||
                                f.getDeclaringClass().equals(Realm.class)) {
                            Log.e("GSONBuild", "Exists Inject");
                            return true;
                        }
                        return false;
                    }

                    @Override
                    public boolean shouldSkipClass(Class<?> clazz) {
                        if (clazz.equals(Inject.class))
                            return true;
                        return false;
                    }
                })
                .create();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I noticed `Realm` was actually the main cause. I still don't know why. So, what I did was passed context and didn't `dependency inject` the `Model` anymore. I use the context to create a `Realm` instance. So, my `Object Class` now look like this

```
public class ObjectClass extends BaseObservable implements Serializable {

    private String TAG = "ObjectClass";

    private String name;
    private String address;
    @Expose(deserialize = false, serialize = false)
    private Context context;

    public ObjectClass() {
    }

    public ObjectClass(Context context) {
        this.context = context;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setname(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    @Bindable
    public String getAddress() {
        return address;
    }

    public void setaddress(String address) {
        this.address = address;
        Realmaddress result = RealmUtils.getInstance(context).where(Realmaddress.class).equalTo("id", address).findFirst();
        if (result != null)
            Log.e(TAG, result.toString());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As you are using `dependency injection` there is something in following line which is not getting `serialised` properly and it's getting in infinite `serialisation` and so you are getting `stackoverflow` error as your memory getting exhausted in some interval of time.

```
((MainApplication) context.getApplicationContext()).getMainAppComponent().inject(this);
```

Either remove above sentence if it's unusable in your code or do it in some other way.

Comment: Well, it's being used. What other way do you mean? I need the `realm` because the Object is being use by the `databinder`. Can I make `Gson` omit that and not concern itself with that?

Comment: @ItuokeAjanlekoko otherway in the sense you can use interfaces to pass/send your data in this case